# How to add session id to each log in winston logger

Tags: node.js, winston

In my node application I'm using winston module to store my application logs. I am getting the log as:

```
2017-11-22T07:16:38.632Z - info: asset type is attached successfully
```

Now I want to add sessionID after timestamp. I want my log as:

```
 2017-11-22T07:16:38.632Z -**sessionId here**- info: asset type is attached successfully.
```

My code which I used for winston logging is:

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const levels = {
  error: 0,
  warn: 1,
  info: 2,
  http: 3,
  verbose: 4,
  debug: 5,
  silly: 6,
  trace: 7
};

var transport = new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
  filename: 'logs/./log',
  datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd.',
  prepend: true,
  json: false,
  level: process.env.ENV === 'development' ? 'debug' : 'info'
});

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  levels: levels,
  transports: [
    transport
  ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

Comment: copy-paste your code, not a picture of your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to custom the log format https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/tree/2.x#custom-log-format

First update your transport :

```
var transport = new (winston...
  ...
  level: process.env.ENV === 'development' ? 'debug' : 'info',
  timestamp: () => {
    let today = new Date();
    return today.toISOString();
  },
  formatter: options => `${options.timestamp()} -${options.meta.sessionId}- ${options.level}: ${options.message}`
});
```

Then, just pass the session ID to your logger **meta** feature :

`logger.info('asset type is attached successfully', {sessionId: 'mySessionID'});`

and you get

> 2017-11-22T14:13:17.697Z -mySessionID- info: asset type is attached successfully

**Edit :** instead of exporting only the winston.logger object, we export an object which requires a sessionId as a parameter, and contains the winston.logger. We also update the transport, so we customize its *formatter* property in the new Logger object. In the *formatter* property, we replace the *meta* declaration with the new *this.sessionId* variable, so we don't use the *meta* property anymore.

logger.js :

```
var transport = new (winston...
  ...
  level: process.env.ENV === 'development' ? 'debug' : 'info',
  timestamp: () => {
    let today = new Date();
    return today.toISOString();
  }
});

class Logger {
  constructor(session) {
    this.sessionId = session;
    this.transport = transport;
    this.transport.formatter = options => `${options.timestamp()} -${this.sessionId}- ${options.level}: ${options.message}`;
    this.logger = new (winston.Logger)({
      levels: levels,
      transports: [this.transport]
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Logger;
```

server.js :

```
const Logger = require('./logger.js');
let logman = new Logger('my_session_id');
let logger = logman.logger;
```

`logger.info('asset type is attached successfully');`

> 2017-11-23T13:13:08.769Z -my_session_id- info: asset type is attached successfully

Comment: Hi, thanks user1851595 for answer but It wouldn't solve my problem. approx 300-400 of lines are to be logged using winston. So, I need to send this meta data 300-400 times in each log. Is there any other way so that I can achieve this by minor changes. Thanks in advance. Do tell me if any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same request and wasn't wild about the solution... I liked the way the standard logger was formatting logs and didn't want to reinvent that wheel. Also, I was hoping for something more compact and I think I found it. I'm not a javascript programmer, so it might not be good coding practice, but it seems to work well for me...

server.js

```
//Initiate winston logging please
const logger = require('winston');
const common = require('winston/lib/winston/common');

function myFormat(options) {
  options.formatter = null
  options.label = helpers.getSessionId(logger.req)
  return common.log(options);
}

var consoleLoggingConfig = {
  timestamp: true,
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL ? process.env.LOG_LEVEL : "info",
  handleExceptions: true,
  humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
  formatter: myFormat
}

logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, consoleLoggingConfig)
logger.info('Winston logging initiated', consoleLoggingConfig)

//Helper to ensure that logger has access to the request object to obtain the session id
app.use(helpers.attachReqToLogger)
module.exports=logger
```

helpers.js

```
// Helper to ensure that the winston logger has the request object on it to obtain the sessionId
helpers.attachReqToLogger = function(req, res, next) {
  logger.req = req
  next();
}
```

Comment: excuse me, were u using Express or Hapi?

Answer (score 0):

```
import winston from "winston";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const { format } = winston;

const commonFormat = [format.timestamp(), format.json()];

const withId = [
    format.printf(({ message, id, ...rest }) => {

        return JSON.stringify(
            {
                // if frontend privide id, use it, else create one
                id: id ?? uuidv4(),
                message,
                ...rest,
            },
            null,
            // prettyPrint seems will overload printf's output
            // so i mannually do this
            4,
        );
    }),
];

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: "debug",
    format: format.combine(...commonFormat, ...withId),
    // ...
```